# How can I create Gift Card for Magento Community Edition?

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1.9, magento-ce

How to create gift card for magento community edition 1.8 or 1.9? Or does anyone know a FREE Gift Card Extension?

Answer (score 2):

Below free giftcard extension  you can use

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/devsters-gift-cards.html

Also you try below links

https://github.com/WarbyParker/Warby_BulkGiftAccount

https://github.com/merchantwarehouse/shopping-cart-integrations/tree/master/magento

Comment: yeah. I've tried that in different versions of magento (1.8.0, 1.8.1 and 1.9). But I encountered this error: CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_Core_Modules 1.8.0.0 conflicts with: community/Devsters_Gift_Cards 0.2.1

Comment: Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: then download it using magento old version  ....  you will get it package from downloader/.cache/community ,Then copy this zip  to your magento 1.8 ya 1.9 and extract extra to specific location

Comment: Have you tried that @AmitBera?

Comment: No, i have suggest that

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm just a beginner. Do you mean I have to install that free extension to lower version of magento then get its package here downloader/.cache/community? And what specific location is it?

Comment: extra this zip  and put this zips files and folders   on  your magento 1.9.0 version